# Laravel Spark is adding 'LocalHost' to the url in Image upload

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-spark

So I have tried creating the symbolic for the spark using following command

```
ln -s /var/www/spark-rewrite/storage/app/public /var/www/spark-rewrite/public/storage
```

But still when I try to upload an image in the settings module the image is not visible .

Although the image is being added to the folder

> /public/storage/profiles/image.jpg

I have found out the issue but don'e know how to fix that

the issue is the src url with which spark tying to fetch the image is like this

> http://localhost/storage/profiles/hlQbtMwPNHITQPjFzuBUiY9MsM4RMvQPkfDfMwOy.jpeg

Since my project has Domain Name the `localhost` will not work can some one help me fix this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  I successfully resolved it by updating the `APP_URL` in the .env file to match my domain.  In my case, I changed `localhost` to `spark.app:8000`.  Initially, I didn't realize that Spark saves the full photo url to the database each time you upload a photo so you'll need to re-upload your photo after changing the .env setting.